# css image becomes over the text

Tags: html, css

**you may think that this question is duplicated, but please check the jsffiddle first to be sure that it is not**

Normally, I just float the image right or left and text becomes floated left of right to it, that works perfectly when I have just on image. but this case I have four images at the corners of a div. I **don't** want the text to be left and right of images, but I **do** want the text to not be hidden.

I mean the text starts bellow the image in the current case, and that what I want to fix.

#### What I have tried

I have tried to put float left and right on the images and give the `.box2` class a clear:both

JSFIDDLe
http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/

Comment: Elements with `position : absolute` do not flow content.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol WOW that is brand new information to me. excellent. However, I can't remove the `absolute` property because I need the images to be in the corners so how could I solve my problem please?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol help please, they guys are giving me completely wrong answers

Comment: your question is really not easy to comprehend! Don't moan about wrong answers and try to be more clear next time. I added an answer anyways ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change to this:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.img1 {
    float:left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.img2 {
    float:right;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.img3 {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.img4 {
    float:right;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3zM6x/8/)**

Comment: Many thanks but this is a wrong solution my friend, you have rolled the two images at the bottom

Comment: I removed `float:left` and `float:right` from the `img3` and `img4`. If you add it then it should be on `right` and `left`

Comment: And you will have to change the overall height of the box as well

Comment: Kindly do that in your jsfiddle, I couldn't understand your point

Comment: you can't float absulote positioned elements

Comment: your jsfiddle didn't solve the problem, check why here please http://jsfiddle.net/3zM6x/5/, you just make the text long so the images becomes at the bottom

Comment: take all your time my friend, i am not in hurry

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3zM6x/8/ and this for full text http://jsfiddle.net/3zM6x/7/

Comment: again thanks but still you have changed my layout :) the height is not fixed anymore. what I need is exactly what you have done but the height of the div is static = 600px. plus, I really believe the position:absolute should be removed  because it is the only way to make the image always at the corner

Comment: Sorry... Got as close as I could... Anyways, I would upvote the question but I am on daily vote limit

Comment: no problem my friend, I appreciate your help and time and efforts with me.

Answer (score 2):

Since all your images are absolute positioned, you could give the box2 div a `position: relative` and then just give box2 also `z-index: 1`.

In short: add:

```
z-index:1;
position: relative;
```

to box2.

Explanation:
When elements aren't positioned statically (the default for all DOM elements is `position: static`) you can play around with their `z-index`. This means the 'level' or 'layer' (as in Photoshop layer) this element is. The default value of `z-index` is 0.
So, putting the text box in a higher 'layer', makes it render above the other layers (the images, which are by default set to `z-index: 0`).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for yours answer, but your solution will make the text above the images, but I want the test to start from left to the image

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I misunderstood the problem. Then what you need to do is use floating, as @imbondbaby suggested. That would be my advice as well for this case :)

Comment: I already tried float but it doesn't work, as I told you in the question, and floating with absolute doesn't work

Comment: Floating doesn't go well with absolute positions. From what I understand, the problem is getting those images to stick to the footer, and still take up the space so text won't get over it or below it.
This is a bit more complicated. Have you looked for solutions on how to stick elements to the bottom of a container?
a quick Google search came up with this:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Give it a try. I didn't try it - but it looks like a nice hack. Lemme know how it went for ya.

Comment: yes I know how to put things at the bottom, that is a different issue. anyway +t to your efforts with mne

Answer (score 2):

**css**

```
.box {
    max-width:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.img1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
}
.img2 {
    position: relative;;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float:right;
}
.img3 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
}
.img4 {
    position: relative;;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float:right;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/10/)

Comment: thanks but you made the text above the image not start from the left of the image.

Comment: you shouldn't add `<br>`, that is just a temporary fixed, I don't want that my friend. anyway +1 to your efforts

Comment: can not change html structure?

Comment: I can change html structure, but change is not good because it is a work-arround. it is not a good solution. making a <br> is wrong because it takes height for nothing and it will make extract space between the text and the images. I hope you got me ?

Comment: This one without change html structure http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/14/ and this one replaced `br` with `div` http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/15/

Comment: I appreciate your help but that is also a work-arround, my friend I need this page for a big company and I can't show them this work arround solution, simply try to resize the window and everything will be missed up. I already +1 your question. I hope there is a standard solution to this problem

Answer (score 2):

based on @Alek his answer and your comment about not wanting to use `br`,`span` or `div` I came up with two suggestions:

The *first* one you float the images at the bottom **and** `float` the parent `.box`:

http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/19/

**or**

Second one is almost the same, except you don't `float` the parent `.box`, but use a clearfix. Personally I don't like clearfixes and avoid using them whenever possible, but just in case you can't float the parent you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/18/

Comment: also your solution is wrong, check why here please http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/21/, I need the div height to be always 600px.  and your solution highly depends on the content of the div, I mean the text. anyway +1 for your efforts with me

Comment: so why don't you just set the height you need on `.box2`? something like this: `.box2 { height: 600px; }`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/22/)

Comment: still you have a problem in this case : http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/28/ where the text is underneath (below) the image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EL5n9/29/ if your content is longer than the parent set the parent `height` and `overflow: scroll`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set your image position to absolute, so that the image overlap the text.

You can simply move the text div bellow the imgae, here is the demo:

[UPDATE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/94HkN/1/)

```
  <div class="box">

    <img class="img1" src="http://s10.postimg.org/7r9itbhs9/default_image.jpg" alt="default image">
    <img class="img2" src="http://s10.postimg.org/7r9itbhs9/default_image.jpg" alt="default image">
    <img class="img3" src="http://s10.postimg.org/7r9itbhs9/default_image.jpg" alt="default image">
    <img class="img4" src="http://s10.postimg.org/7r9itbhs9/default_image.jpg" alt="default image">
</div>
                <div class="box2">this is the text
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not what I want, I want the text still be inside the div. not outside it